# Set Firmware Option for Vsphere VM created by salt-cloud

Tags: vmware-vsphere, saltstack, salt-cloud

I am trying to create a VM hosted in Vsphere using salt-cloud and need to set the boot options for this VM.

From what I can tell there isn't an actual option for this so I guessing it needs to be part of my `extra_config` section, however I am not fully sure how to implement this.

My `extra_config` currently looks like this

```
  extra_config:
    vim.vm.BootOptions.efiSecureBootEnabled: True
```

But I get an error in Vsphere that says :

> A specified parameter was not correct: config.extraConfig["vim.vm.BootOptions.efiSecureBootEnabled"]

This was a guess from the VmWare documentation https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1ef6c336-7bef-477d-b9bb-caa1767d7e30/82521f49-9d9a-42b7-b19b-9e6cd9b30db1/vim.vm.BootOptions.html

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template with the settings you need and just build from that.

Comment: I've tried that in the past and it didn't work the way I would like, would be better to get this working if possible. Thanks for your comment though